# sbt: how to depend on sub module of a git project

Tags: scala, github, sbt, smile

I have a project that depends on:

```
"com.github.haifengl" % "smile-core" % "1.1.0",
"com.github.haifengl" % "smile-scala_2.11" % "1.1.0",
```

and want to modify sbt to use the latest master of the same project from github.

I've done this with other projects like this:

```
lazy val myProject = Project("myProject", file("."))
  .settings(commonSettings: _*)
  .dependsOn(smileProject)


lazy val smileProject = RootProject(uri("https://github.com/haifengl/smile"))
```

However, this fails with:

```
 unresolved dependency: default#smile_2.11;0.1-SNAPSHOT: not found
```

which kinda makes sense. Following [this example](https://github.com/haifengl/smile/blob/master/core/build.sbt)

```
lazy val smileProject = ProjectRef(uri("https://github.com/haifengl/smile"), "smile-core")
```

I get:

```
[error] No project 'smile-core' in 'https://github.com/haifengl/smile'.
[error] Valid project IDs: smile
```

[smile-core](https://github.com/haifengl/smile/blob/master/core/build.sbt) seems like the right name.

UPDATE: Adding the .git extension

```
lazy val smileProject = ProjectRef(uri("https://github.com/haifengl/smile.git"), "smile-core")
```

also gives:

```
[error] No project 'smile-core' in 'https://github.com/haifengl/smile.git'.
[error] Valid project IDs: benchmark, core, data, demo, graph, interpolation, math, nlp, plot, root, scala, shell
```

... which seems like an improvement

Comment: Looks you're missing the `.git` extension in the URL: `ProjectRef(uri("https://github.com/haifengl/smile.git"), "smile-core")`

Comment: Doesn't help. Have updated the question.

Comment: Ah -- did help. Had the wrong module name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if this "[Git Subproject Compile-time Dependencies in Sbt](http://blog.xebia.com/git-subproject-compile-time-dependencies-in-sbt/)" from 2015 could work:

```
lazy val root = Project("root", sbt.file(".")).dependsOn(smileProject, ...)
lazy val smileProject = ProjectRef(uri("https://github.com/haifengl/smile.git"), "core")
```

Comment: Makes no difference: I get "No project 'smile-core' in 'https://github.com/haifengl/smile.git'."

Comment: Ah -- need both the .git extension and "smile-core"->"core"  as the module.